# Update components element from a different component

Tags: blazor

Im trying to change the classes of an element inside one of my components from a page, but the classes never change. I put a `Console.Writeline` inside the function, and the function is definitley running.

The `CircleClass` variable by default is set to `"danger"`, and that works properly, the div starts off with the `danger class`. The console.writeline confirms that the variable is being changed, it just isn't updating the element.

Code in component:

```
<div class="circle @CircleClass"></div>

@code {
    private string CircleClass = "danger";

    public void ChangeStatus(int status)
    {
        switch (status)
        {
            case 0:
                CircleClass = "idle";
                break;
            case 1:
                CircleClass = "safety";
                break;
            case 2:
                CircleClass = "danger";
                break;
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"{status} Circle: {CircleClass}");
    }
}
```

### First Attempt

```
@page "/"

@Inject Nav nav

<button @onclick="@(e => nav.ChangeStatus(2))">Two</button>
```

In `Startup.cs` I added this:

```
services.AddSingleton<Nav>();
```

### Second Attempt

```
@page "/"

<button @onclick="@(e => ChangeStatus(2))">Two</button>

private void ChangeStatus(int status)
{
    Nav nav = new Nav();
    nav.ChangeStatus(status);
}
```

I think it may have something to do with it creating a new instance of the class which isn't able to change the classes of the elements I need changing, although I believe that should be solved when using `AddSingleton`.

Anyone know what could be causing this issue?

---

Calling the function inside of the component confirms that the function actually works.

#### Component:

```
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    ChangeStatus(1);
}
```

---

What I am trying:

#### Nav.razor

```
<li id="status">
    <div class="circle @CircleClass"></div>
</li>

@code {
    private string CircleClass = "danger";

    public void ChangeStatus(int status)
    {
        switch (status)
        {
            case 0:
                CircleClass = "idle";
                break;
            case 1:
                CircleClass = "safety";
                break;
            case 2:
                CircleClass = "danger";
                break;
            default:
                CircleClass = "idle";
                break;
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"{status} Circle: {CircleClass}");

        InvokeAsync(() =>
        {
            StateHasChanged();
        });
    }
}
```

#### Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddRazorPages();
    services.AddServerSideBlazor();

    services.AddSingleton<Nav>();
}
```

#### Index.razor

```
@page "/"

@inject Nav nav 

<button @onclick="@(e => nav.ChangeStatus(0))">Zero</button>
<button @onclick="@(e => nav.ChangeStatus(1))">One</button>
<button @onclick="@(e => nav.ChangeStatus(2))">Two</button>
```

---

In my code examples above, I am using buttons to try to run functions in the nav component from a page, but eventually I am going to run these functions from different places that wont be pages without direct user input.

---

The `Nav` component is defined/created in my `MainLayout`, it isn't directly applied to the `Index` page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make a service that can help manage the component.

**Firstly:**

- Make the service and move the function that updates the component to it (in this case `ChangeStatus()`).
- Add an event to your new service and trigger it at the end of the `ChangeStatus()` function.

#### services/MyService.cs

```
using System;

namespace MyAppName.Services
{
    public delegate void MyEventHandler();

    public class MyService
    {
        public event MyEventHandler MyEvent;
        public string CircleClass = "danger";

        public void ChangeStatus(int status)
        {
            switch (status)
            {
                case 0:
                    CircleClass = "idle";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    CircleClass = "safety";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    CircleClass = "danger";
                    break;
            }

            // Fire event
            MyEvent?.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

**Secondly:**

- Add service as a `Singleton` in your blazor app.
- For easier access, add the Services namespace to your `_Imports.razor` file.

#### Adding service

```
// In Blazor Server-Side
// open Startup.cs and add:

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // [..]

    services.AddSingleton<MyService>();
}

// In Blazor WebAssembly
// open Program.cs and add:

public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    // [..]

    builder.Services.AddSingleton<MyService>();
}
```

#### Add service to _Imports.razor

```
// This will only work if the namespace
// for your service is the MyAppName.Services.
// If you put your service in the Services folder
// you should be fine unless you renamed the namespace.
@using MyAppName.Services
```

**Thirdly:**

- Inject service into your component.
- Subscribe to the event in your component and create a function to run `StateHasChanges()` when the event fires.

#### Component.razor

```
// At the top:
@inject MyService myService

// Subscribe to event and create function
@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        myService.MyEvent+= UpdateState;
    }

    private void UpdateState()
    {
        // Need to use InvokeAsync, atleast
        // on Blazor Server-Side
        InvokeAsync(() =>
        {
            StateHasChanged();
        });
    }
}
```

**Finally:**

- Run `ChangeStatus()` function in the service from somewhere else (in this case, from a page)

#### Index.razor

```
@page "/"

@inject MyService myService

<button @onclick="@(e => myService.ChangeStatus(0))">Test 0</button>
<button @onclick="@(e => myService.ChangeStatus(1))">Test 1</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this. I think you don't need Nav service. You can call and change class value from page itself.

**Inside index page**

**HTML**

```
<Nav @ref="navComp"></Nav>

<button @onclick="@(e => navComp.ChangeStatus(0))">Zero</button>
<button @onclick="@(e => navComp.ChangeStatus(1))">One</button>
<button @onclick="@(e => navComp.ChangeStatus(2))">Two</button>
```

**C# Code**

```
@code {
Nav navComp;

    //other code
}
```

**Inside Nav component**

**HTML**

```
<h3>Nav</h3>
<li id="status">
    <div class="circle @CircleClass"></div>
</li>
```

**C# Code**

```
@code {
    private string CircleClass = "danger";

    public void ChangeStatus(int status)
    {
        switch (status)
        {
            case 0:
                CircleClass = "idle";
                break;
            case 1:
                CircleClass = "safety";
                break;
            case 2:
                CircleClass = "danger";
                break;
            default:
                CircleClass = "idle";
                break;
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"{status} Circle: {CircleClass}");

        InvokeAsync(() =>
        {
            StateHasChanged();
        });
    }
}
```

you can see the output right here..

[image: output]

Comment: This works, but in my case, the `<Nav>` element isn't directly applied to the `Index` page. Is there a way of accessing the functions for the element when it isn't directly on that specific page, but rather in its Layout (I have the `<Nav> element in `MainLayout`)?